# Xcode Swift SpriteKit SkSpriteNode Y value isn't moving but X is

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite, skaction

In the move Action, the Y value isn't changing and i don't know why because the X value is changing. The changeY variable is doing its job with the correct value of 5.0 or -5.0 but the Y value on the "player" SkSpriteNode isn't changing. Please help.

```
 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    let percent = touchLocation.x / size.width
    let newAngle = percent * 180 - 180
    print(newAngle)
    if playButtonPressed{

        var changeY = 0.0
        if newAngle >= -180{
            changeY = 5.0
        }
        else{
            changeY = -5.0
        }
        player.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
        print(changeY)
        var move = SKAction.moveBy(x: -(player.position.x+1), y: CGFloat(changeY), duration: 2000.0)
        player.run(move)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you ultimate goal is, but your calculations seems of. Especially the fact that the duration for the movement is 2000 seconds. That's more than 30 minutes(!) The x-calculations also suggests that you actually planned to use `moveTo` rather than `moveBy` as you're currently doing.

The below is based on your code but as I'm not sure what your actually aiming for this does the following: Moves left+up if the touch is on the left-hand side of the screen, moves down+right if the touch is on the right-hand side of the screen...

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if playButtonPressed {
        let percent = touchLocation.x / size.width
        let newAngle = percent * 180 - 180
        player.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0

        let moveRightAndUp = touchLocation.x>size.width/2
        let changeY: CGFloat = moveRightAndUp ? 5.0 : -5.0
        let changeX: CGFloat = moveRightAndUp ? 1.0 : -1.0
        let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: changeX, y: changeY, duration: 1/60)
        player.run(move)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so when i added that the y started working but i was wondering if there is a way to have the "player" node moving at a constant speed which just travels in the direction of newAngle. Thank you for your help